# Erlang - Split a list into lists based on value

Tags: erlang, list

I am trying to split this list

```
List = [[<<"5">>, <<"54">>], [<<"00">>], [<<"35">>, <<"54">>, <<"45">>, <<"55">>], [<<"00">>],[ <<"5">>]]
```

into

```
List = [[<<"5">>, <<"54">>], [<<"35">>, <<"54">>, <<"45">>, <<"55">>], [<<"5">>]]
```

Basically based on the <<"00">>

What is the best BIF to go about this, I have some code, but its sloppy, and Im trying to learn.

Thanks

EDIT:

Tried the following, does not work

Done2 = lists:splitwith( [<<"00">>], Done1),

EDIT:
This Line works!

```
7> lists:splitwith(fun(A) -> A == [<<"00">>] end, List).
{[],
 [[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],
  [<<"00">>],
  [<<"35">>,<<"54">>,<<"45">>,<<"55">>],
  [<<"00">>],
  [<<"5">>]]}
```

However I need something a little more complicated: like when the delim is [<<"00">>,<<"23">>]

```
9> List = [[<<"5">>,<<"54">>], [<<"00">>,<<"23">>], [<<"35">>,<<"54">>], [<<"5">
>], [<<"00">>, <<"23">>]].

[[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],
 [<<"00">>,<<"23">>],
 [<<"35">>,<<"54">>],
 [<<"5">>],
 [<<"00">>,<<"23">>]]

10> lists:splitwith(fun(A) -> A == [<<"00">>] end, List).
{[],
 [[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],
  [<<"00">>,<<"23">>],
  [<<"35">>,<<"54">>],
  [<<"5">>],
  [<<"00">>,<<"23">>]]}

11> lists:splitwith(fun(A) -> A == [<<"00">>,<<"23">>] end, List).
{[],
 [[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],
  [<<"00">>,<<"23">>],
  [<<"35">>,<<"54">>],
  [<<"5">>],
  [<<"00">>,<<"23">>]]}
12>
```

No luck there

Comment: according to this link http://www3.erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#split-2 , u need to use splitwith

Comment: It doesn't seem that `lists:splitwith(fun(A) -> A == [<<"00">>] end, List).` returns what you ask for in your question. Result is not same as what you have in your second `List`. Second lists is not spitted at all. It seems like with `[<<"00">>]` removed. Can you define what would you like more precisely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood your requirements correctly. Here is a possible solution. It will split the list on any delimiter like [<<"00">> | _ ].

```
1> List = [[<<"5">>, <<"54">>], [<<"00">>], [<<"35">>, <<"54">>, <<"45">>, <<"55">>], [<<"00">>, <<"23">> ],[ <<"5">>]].
[[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],
 [<<"00">>],
 [<<"35">>,<<"54">>,<<"45">>,<<"55">>],
 [<<"00">>,<<"23">>],
 [<<"5">>]]
2> List2 =  [ X || X <- List, case X of [ <<"00">> | _ ] -> false; _ -> true end].                                      
[[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],
 [<<"35">>,<<"54">>,<<"45">>,<<"55">>],
 [<<"5">>]]
```

Comment: Your solution doesn't actually split the list... On the other hand, given the original question it was a "correct" answer... :-)

Answer (score 1):

1> List = [[<<"5">>,<<"54">>], [<<"00">>,<<"23">>], [<<"35">>,<<"54">>], [<<"5">>], [<<"00">>, <<"23">>]].
[[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],
 [<<"00">>,<<"23">>],
 [<<"35">>,<<"54">>],
 [<<"5">>],
 [<<"00">>,<<"23">>]]

2> Delimiter = [<<"00">>,<<"23">>].
[<<"00">>,<<"23">>]

3> lists:filter(fun(L) -> L /= Delimiter end, List).
[[<<"5">>,<<"54">>],[<<"35">>,<<"54">>],[<<"5">>]]